# Find if any column in pandas dataframe is NULL and state this in new column

Tags: python, pandas, nonetype

I have a dataframe, something like this

```
import pandas as pd
 
dic = {'animal':["cat", "dog", "rabbit"],
        'colour': ["yellow", None, "red"],
        'size':[None, "large", "small"]}
 
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

   animal  colour   size
0     cat  yellow   None
1     dog    None  large
2  rabbit     red  small
```

I want to create a new column that contains `True` if any other column is null and `False` if not.

```
   animal  colour   size   bool
0     cat  yellow   None   True
1     dog    None  large   True
2  rabbit     red  small  False
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 functions for that: `pandas.isna` and `pandas.any`:

```
df['bool'] = df.isna().any(axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```py
df['bool'] = df.isna().sum(axis=1).astype(bool)
```

the idea behind this line of code is that True is casted to 1 in bool -> int conversions (implicitly done by the .sum(axis=1) method) and that any non zero integer is casted to True by int -> bool conversions (explicitly done by the .astype(bool) method).